# Python で入力されたｎ個の数の平均値、最大値、最小値を出力したい

Tags: python

入力から得た数字の平均値、最大値、最小値を求めるコードを書きたいのですが、上手くいきません。
どのように修正をすればいいですか？
現段階では最大値を求めるだけのコードをテストとしか書いていないです。おそらく最大値を出すコードを書く場所は適切な場所ではないと思います。どこに書けばいいのでしょうか？

```
def listofname():
    members, scores = {'name': []}, {'Score': []}
    while 1:
        Students = input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished ")
        if Students == 'done': break
        members['name'] += [Students]
        Score = input('Enter score ')
        scores['Score'] += [int(Score)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listofname()

    maxOfValue = scores[0]

    for i in range(1,len()):

        if(maxOfValue < scores[i]):

            maxOfValue = scores[i]

    print("max number:", scores)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最大値と最小値は `max()`, `min()` 関数、平均値は [statistics 数理統計関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/statistics.html) モジュールの `mean()` が利用可能です。

```py
def ScoreList():
    scores = {'name': [], 'score': []}
    while True:
        name = input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished ")
        if name == 'done': break
        scores['name'] += [name]
        score = input('Enter score ')
        scores['score'] += [int(score)]

    return scores

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = ScoreList()
    maxScore = max(scores['score'])
    print("max number:", maxScore)
```

Comment: このコードだとmax numberしか表示されないのですが。自分なりに少し手を加えて、編集してみたのですがうまくいきませんでした。ScoreListの内容もプリントしたいのですが、どこにScoreList()を記入すればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: `scores = ScoreList()` 以降に `print(scores)` を入れてください。また、「最大値と最小値は max(), min() 関数、平均値は statistics 数理統計関数 モジュールの mean() が利用可能です。」をよく読んで下さい。